# Unable to capture form a web camera using OpenCV 2.3.1

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I try to run the example shown [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture). Unfortunately it dosen't work. The camera won't be open. The program fails on line

```
VideoCapture cap(0); 
if(!cap.isOpened())
    return -1; // on this line the program fails
```

I'm sure that the camera works becouse when I run a program to capture images (cheese) everything works fine.

I using 64bit ubuntu 11.04

I compile the program with the following comand

`g++ -Wall -o my_program my_program.cpp -lopencv_highgu`

It seems like there were no camera. But in other programs the camera works.

Any ideas why it dosen't work?

Comment: What camera are you using? Is it on [this list](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS)?

Comment: I'm using a logitech cam. But I don't know the model. But on Mint 10 32 bit system and openCV 2.0 my cam have worked fine.

Comment: How about `VideoCapture cap(-1);` ?

Comment: I found the solution. I upgrate my ubuntu to 11.10 and the camera works

Comment: @KrystianSola Thanks for taking the time to tell us the answer but since this question is still marked as "unanswered", others will come here to try and solve to the problem - and might not notice your comment. Please either post your solution as an answer, then accept it - or (since this will be of questionable use to others) delete it. Many thanks and welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I upgraded my ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10.

After that the camera works fine.